# Usage of the word "lain"

Tags: word-usage

Today I discovered the total timesuck that is ngram and have been running a bunch of words thru it.
I was somewhat surprised by the trend of the word "lain". Given that it's pretty much a done deal as far as the lie/lay distinction goes, why is it trending up in the past few years
[image]

Comment: Does ngram have a concept of unique title, so that multiple contemporary reprints by different publishers of a text from, say, 1885, wouldn't result in a skewing of the stats?

Comment: @TimR honestly no idea, like I said I discovered ngram only today and have been goofing off!

Comment: Weird. I just search on Google Books for "lain" in quotes in the 21st century and got no results. *lain* without quotes gives several books by people called Lain and a few works such as A Biography of Lain Singh Bangdel, but no other results in the first 10 pages. My guess is that NGrams isn't working properly (or as expected).

Answer (score 1):

A good question.  My guess is ... a TV series from 1998:

[image: poster]

Also a video game with the same name.

Comment: I didn't do a good job of screen capture, when I go back and look the upward trend starts in 1980, well before the show.
Here is the link to the ngram results
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lain&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: Probably in part due to Lain Singh Bangdel, James Lain Potter, Gordon Lain Ellis, Larry Lain, all of whom wrote books between 1980 and 2000.